# LibVlc android getting all tracks

Tags: android, libvlc

I can't find much documentation on the process of getting all of the media tracks (video audio and subtitles) using libvlc on android.

From what I understand, I have to parse the media, and I'm doing it like this:

```
Media media = new Media(libVLC, Uri.parse(url));
media.setEventListener(new IMedia.EventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(IMedia.Event event) {
            switch (event.type){
                case IMedia.Event.ParsedChanged:
                    if(event.getParsedStatus() == IMedia.ParsedStatus.Done){
                        Log.i("App", "Parse done, track count " + media.getTrackCount());
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        for(int i=0; i<media.getTrackCount(); i++){
                            Log.i("App", "Track " + i + ": " + gson.toJson(media.getTrack(i)));
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
media.parseAsync();
vlc.setMedia(media);
vlc.play();
```

The results I get from this are odd: sometimes I get one track only, the video track, but sometimes I also get the audio track, so two tracks total.

The problem is that the media also have a subtitle track, so there must be a way for me to get all three tracks (Playing the same exact media with vlc on windows shows, indeed, all three tracks).

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I need a way to dynamically get all tracks, the media could have n tracks so I don't know the exact number. This is just a test and I know there are three tracks.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to get the tracks from media, use VLC MediaPlayer object, VLC media player provides methods to get Audio Tracks, Video Tracks and Subtitle tracks using MediaPlayer object.

```
mMediaPlayer!!.setEventListener { 
            when (p0?.type) {
            MediaPlayer.Event.Opening-> {
                val audioTracks = mMediaPlayer!!.audioTracks
                val subtitleTracks = mMediaPlayer!!.spuTracks
                val videoTracks = mMediaPlayer!!.videoTracks
            }
        }
```

You can iterate over the lists to get individual tracks.

Comment: If i get the track with the MediaPlayer object in an event, say a button click, after the media is loaded, I get the right number of tracks. If i do this in the Opening listener, I still get 0 tracks. So the problem seems to happen because I'm getting the tracks too early